# How do I update data in a Spring WebFlow Model and Pass it back to the same view

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

How do I update data in a Spring WebFlow Model and Pass it back to the same view.

I have a project that I am working on and if the user picks a item from a selectbox I need to go back to the server in fill in some data to the model that needs to be displayed on the view.

You can see from my view-state that once the item is picked I setoff a transition for SelectBoxPicked and call my controller with the model but how do I return the updated model to the view?

Can someone please tell me what to put into my java (controller) code and also in my flow.xml to make this work.

```
<view-state id="SchoolVisitReport" view="SchoolVisitReport.jsp" model="visit" >
 <transition on="submit" to="addVisit">
  <evaluate expression="flowActions.validateVisit(visit, messageContext)"/>
 </transition>

 <transition on="loadSchools" to="SchoolVisitReport" >
  <evaluate expression="flowActions.initializeSelectableSchools(visit)" result="flowScope.selectableSchools"/>
 </transition>

 <transition on="SelectBoxPicked" to="SchoolVisitReport" >
  <evaluate expression="flowActions.fillDetails(visit)" />
 </transition>


  <transition on="cancel" to="endState" bind="false"/>
</view-state>
```

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html#view-transitions
look at event handler. is this what you want to do?

Comment: yes.... post anwser so I can give you credit.. also email me at techsjs2012 at gmail so we can be friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That basic approach works; we've used it ourselves. [The Java code you call from the evaluate method can return `false` to prevent the transition](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html#view-transitions), although that will just transition back to the current state anyway. I believe anything other than `false` will take your transition.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean but this.. I am trying to find sample of the code to put into my controller to update the model and pass it back to the view

Comment: You passed it in as a parameter, so you just update it in the method. No need to "pass it back".

Comment: I'm saying that your flow.xml is correct, and there's nothing special you need to do in your java code. Just update the `visit` object that you passed in.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to take a look at http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html#view-transitions 
particularly the section on event handler